# Как определить тип typename в template на этапе компиляции?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть проблемный шаблонный метод который выполняет простые действия с объектами типа `T` ( например `+=` или `+` или любой другой )

но для некоторых типов этот оператор не определен и компилятор выдает ошибку:

> error C2679: binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'Некоторый_тип'

```
template < typename T >
T Foo ( const T & value )
{
   T buf += value;
   return buf;
}
```

я могу использовать `!std::is_same <T, неугодный_тип>` чтобы определить тип и решить что с ним делать, но компилятор не понимает что я решаю эту проблему сам и ругается когда я использую метод с типом без определения += как здесь: `Foo < Тот_самый_тип > ( значение );`

есть ли возможность на этапе компиляции отсечь исключительные ситуации?

что-то вроде

```
template < typename T >
T Foo ( const T & value )
{
#if T Тот_самый_тип
           T buf = value;
#else
           T buf += value;
#endif
           return buf;
}
```

я понимаю что могу сделать специализацию для шаблона, но делать ее из-за одной строчки кажется не оптимальным

PS: вариант должен подходить и для gcc и для msvs2010

Comment: `T buf += value;` Вы уверены?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если вам нужно различить, есть ли в типе `T` оператор `+`, вам придётся заняться метапрограммированием на шаблонах, известном как «шаблонная магия».

Итак, начнём. Во-первых, напишем вспомогательную структуру, которая определяет доступность сложения:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class has_addition
{
    // Эта функция скомпилируется только если выражение
    //     std::declval<C>() + std::declval<C>()
    // имеет смысл. То есть, выражение t1 + t1, где
    // t1 и t2 имеют тип C.
    template <typename C> static std::true_type test( decltype(
            std::declval<C>() + std::declval<C>()
        )* );

    // Эта функция скомпилируется всегда
    template <typename> static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    // test<T>(0) есть вызов первой функции, если она скомпилировалась
    // и второй, если нет. аргумент 0 подходит в обоих случаях,
    // так как первая функция получает указатель
    // соответственно decltype(test<T>(0)) будет true_type
    // или false_type, а value - true или false
    // случай, когда первая функция не компилируется, работает из-за
    // принципа SFINAE
    enum { value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value };
};
```

Отлично, мы на полпути к решению. Теперь осталось воспользоваться им:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class X
{
public:

    // воспользуемся опять SFINAE, для этого применим стандартный
    // шаблон enable_if. SFINAE работает лишь на шаблонных функциях,
    // поэтому добавим фиктивный шаблон
    // это скомпилируется только если has_addition<T1>::value == false
    // то есть если значения типа T нельзя складывать
    template <typename T1 = T>
    typename std::enable_if<!has_addition<T1>::value, void>::type use(T1 t)
    {
        std::cout << "without addition" << std::endl;
        T1 tt = t;
    }

    // а это скомпилируется только если has_addition<T1>::value == true
    // то есть если значения типа T можно складывать
    template <typename T1 = T>
    typename std::enable_if<has_addition<T1>::value, void>::type use(T1 t)
    {
        std::cout << "with addition" << std::endl;
        auto tt = t + t;
    }
};
```

Всё!

Вот [такой код](http://ideone.com/7GNE3B):

```
int main()
{
    X<int> x1; x1.use(1);
    X<void*> x2; x2.use(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

выдаёт

> with addition
>   without addition

---

**Обновление:** К сожалению, компилятор Visual Studio 2010 не настолько продвинут, так что код пришлось упростить и сделать более прямолинейным. (Для Visual Studio 2013 переделки не нужны.) Вот результат:

```
// precompiled header Visual Studio
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class has_addition
{
    // не поддерживается decltype в enum-константе -> откатываемся на трюк с размерами
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    // нету declval, эмулируем вручную. сама функция, понятно, не нужна
    template<typename C>
    static C generateValue();

    template <typename C> static yes& test( decltype(
            generateValue<C>() + generateValue<C>()
        )* );
    template <typename> static no& test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes) };
};

template<class T>
class X
{
public:

    // нельзя использовать значения параметров шаблона по умолчанию
    // используем явное указание шаблонного параметра, прячем в дополнительную функцию
    void use(T t)
    {
        use_impl<T>(t);
    }

private:
    template <typename T1>
    typename std::enable_if<!has_addition<T1>::value, void>::type use_impl(T1 t)
    {
        std::cout << "without addition" << std::endl;
        T1 tt = t;
    }

    template <typename T1>
    typename std::enable_if<has_addition<T1>::value, void>::type use_impl(T1 t)
    {
        std::cout << "with addition" << std::endl;
        auto tt = t + t;
    }

};

int main()
{
    X<int> x1; x1.use(1);
    X<void*> x2; x2.use(nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Наверняка @Abyx придумает решение поизящнее.

Comment: Благодарю =) реализовал я конечно по своему, но использовал вашу идею с перегруженными функциями с std::enable_if
разве что поставил эту конструкцию в качестве необязательного параметра самой функции

Comment: @haku: Угу, можно и так, и так. Главное, чтобы студия не ругалась, а то она привередливая.

Comment: @Abyx: Я пытался сделать изящно, но получилось только в лоб. Сумеете покороче?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, то Вы можете исключить неугодный тип с помощью `std::is_same <T, неугодный_тип>`. Тогда Ваша проблема может быть решена с помощью `std::enabled_if`:

```
template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same <T, неугодный_тип>::value, T>::type
Foo(const T & value)
{
    T buf = value;
    return buf;
}

template < typename T >
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same <T, неугодный_тип>::value, T>::type
Foo(const T & value)
{
    T buf += value;
    return buf;
}
```

P.S. Я не проверял на MSVC10, так как не имею его.

Comment: Да такая конструкция работает в студии
спасибо! очень помогли =)

Comment: Жаль, что нельзя пометить как ответ сразу 2 и более. В купе с первым постом получилось то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Правильный подход это специализация. Если из-за нее много копипаста, стоит подумать о рефакторинге и\или применить обходные маневры. Если с рефакторингом не получается, то... все равно правильно использовать специализацию. Ну и совсем в клининических случаях допустимо применять макросы, но это бывает совсем редко, в моей практике было один раз.

Не надо специализировать всю большую функцию, спициализируйте только одну строчку! Я часто использую такой ход:

```
template<typename T>
void SpecialSmallFunction(T value)
{
    // обобщенные операции
}

template<>
void SpecialSmallFunction<Foo>(Foo value)
{
    // сециализированные для Foo операции
}

template<typename T>
void BigFunction(T value)
{
   // много обобщенного кода
   SpecialSmallFunction(value);
   // много обобщенного кода
}
```

Смысл в том, что для того чтобы не копипастить `много обобщенного кода` мы выносим `специализированный код` в маленькие функции которые проще поддерживать.

Ваш случай самый простой - используйте специализацию.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется тут подойдет

```
if constexper(std::is_same<T,int>::value){
bad_function;
} else {
good_function;}
```